# how to solve compile error android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, sdk

[image: both 2 lines shows]

both 2 lines shows the support library should not the different version 25 then compile sdk version 24...

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "waqar.constitutionofindia"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As you said. change your compileSdkVersion to 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 25 or change the libraries to an appropriate 24 API level build

Answer (score 0):

You can write + like below, it will automatically pick version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

similary for other one too

Comment: This is bad! You should always version lock libraries to prevent incompatibilities and you always know what version you are compiling against.

Answer (score 0):

When this Error shows up, you should always check all your activities.java files and make sure you have no error. that's where it always originates from.

And if all is well then simply change your compile SDK version like it's mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

First change `compileSdkVersion` to the latest SDK version and then use

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:<latest_version>'
```

Example:

```
compileSdkVersion 28

dependencies
{
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```